# Moving an imagebutton in the screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

i have a problem in android, first i wanted to have a button which i move every 2 secs to a different place on the screen, but i couldn't do that (if anyone knows how that would be very helpful).
Anywayz my other way was to make 5 different buttons in different locations and move with the setVisibility() function, but it crashes in the middle i dont know why, here's the code:

```
final ImageButton[] face = new ImageButton[5];

    face[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
    face[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton2);
    face[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton3);
    face[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton4);
    face[4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton5);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        face[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    Thread timer=new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;true;i++)
            {
                if(i==5)
                {
                    i=0;
                }
                Log.v("VISIBLE AT I = ",Integer.toString(i));
                face[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.v("CATCH","CATCH");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Log.v("SLEPT","SLEPT");
                face[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  // IT CRASHES HERE
                Log.v("INVISIBLE AT I = ",Integer.toString(i));
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();
```

If anyone can help me that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of doing this with an animation? If you're targeting Honeycomb, you can use a [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html); for earlier platforms you can use a [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

As for your crashes, you can only modify UI elements from the UI thread, not from a separate thread. You'd need to signal back, or use one of the (very good) helpers to handle this, such as AsyncTask.

See: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Lorne is right, crash is because you are trying to use a UI element from a background thread. You can either use handler or AsyncTask, or you could just take everything inside of your thread and do it on the main thread instead.

Comment: @Lorne, i'm still a beginner at android, i'm not sure how to use animation yet, if there are any tutorials for dummies online (especially videos) that'd be great

Comment: Animation in android is actually quite easy...the framework is very powerful and does a lot of things for you. The property-based animation in Honeycomb is much more elegant and powerful, but the older pre-Honeycomb approach isn't that hard.

There are many animation tutorials online...I found this one with Google and it seems quite beginner friendly:

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-1/

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-2/

Comment: it's actually great lorne thanks, but it kind of limits me and there are more specific questions that i can't understand, i dont want to be a load but arent there any more tutorials that would make me understand the whole thing for A to Z?. thanks alot by the way :)

Comment: And also, i dont get how to move the button with animation, from the tutorials the animation didnt move the text as it ended in the same place as in its layout

Comment: To make the text end up in a different place, you just change the parameters of the translate animation. The android:toXDelta="0%" and android:toYDelta="0%" settings are telling the animation to end up back in the same place...an X and Y delta (change) of 0%. You can change those values to make your button end up in a different place...for example, you could use android:toXDelta="80" to have your button end up 80 pixels to the right of its original position, and android:toYDelta="-20" to end up 20 pixels above its original position.